# Slow Queries, memory utilization seems low, "Database Error" messages when under only moderate load

Tags: memory, mariadb

I have a site that is set up just like the other 20 except this one is not handling database traffic like the others. It has 24 processors, 196 gig of ram. Yet under large load I see know more used than 5.6gig using `htop` and `free` and `top`. When the machine is nearly idle it uses 2.6gigs - none of other machines use this little. One of my 8 processor machines is typically at 15 gig when nearly idle.

I use the same software to auto tune the `mariadb` config file, all boxes using `nginx`, and `php74`.

I have many slow queries and an entire log file of messages that include

```
[Warning] Aborted connection 34 to db: 'mysite_com_EnfJ52WV' user: 'theuserco3v94' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I have rebuilt the site on another hypervisor, and the issues still remain.
I would appreciate much any ideas, suggestions or reasons why this is happening?

- First the error log:

  ```
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 60800630784, chunk size = 134217728
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.16 started; log sequence number 3516889734036; transaction id 64889121
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::1'.
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:57 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
  Jan  6 19:11:57 thesite mariadbd[3624]: Version: '10.6.16-MariaDB-1:10.6.16+maria~ubu2004-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution 
  Jan  6 19:11:58 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240106 19:11:58
  Jan  6 19:16:51 thesite mariadbd[3624]: 2024-01-06 19:16:51 34 [Warning] Aborted connection 34 to db: 'thesite_com_EnfJ52WV' user: 'thesiteco3v94' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
  ```
- The config file:

  ```
  max_connections     = 100
  connect_timeout     = 5
  wait_timeout        = 60
  max_allowed_packet  = 64M
  thread_cache_size        = 128
  sort_buffer_size    = 4M
  bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
  tmp_table_size      = 256M
  max_heap_table_size = 256M

  #
  # * MyISAM
  #
  # This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
  # the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.

  myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
  key_buffer_size     = 16M
  open-files-limit    = 500000
  table_open_cache    = 16000
  myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
  concurrent_insert   = 2
  read_buffer_size    = 2M
  read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
  #
  # * Query Cache Configuration
  #
  # Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
  query_cache_limit       = 128K
  query_cache_size        = 0
  # for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
  query_cache_type        = 0

  innodb_log_file_size    = 7246M
  innodb_buffer_pool_size = 57969M
  innodb_log_buffer_size  = 14492M
  innodb_file_per_table   = 1
  innodb_open_files   = 500000
  innodb_io_capacity  = 500000
  innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
  ```
- slow querys: (just two but many like it )

  ```
  # Time: 240106 19:36:18
  # User@Host: thesiteco3v94[thesiteco3v94] @ localhost []
  # Thread_id: 803  Schema: thesite_com_EnfJ52WV  QC_hit: No
  # Query_time: 12.114378  Lock_time: 0.000152  Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 13885
  # Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 198962
  # Tmp_tables: 1  Tmp_disk_tables: 1  Tmp_table_sizes: 34226176
  # Full_scan: No  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: Yes  Tmp_table_on_disk: Yes
  # Filesort: Yes  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0  Priority_queue: No
  SET timestamp=1704569778;
  SELECT   DISTINCT  wp_posts.*, SUM( COALESCE( pvc.count, 0 ) ) AS post_views
              FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) LEFT JOIN wp_post_views pvc ON pvc.id = wp_posts.ID AND pvc.type = 4
              WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (1402,1691,4351,28684,28692,30874,36540,36579,36581,36583,36589,37011,37014,37015,37017,38591,38599,38601,38604,38646,38648,38649,38651,38652,38655,38657,38800,38944,38945,38946,38947,39181,39642,39650,39661,39664,39678,39713,39714,39715,39716,39717,39718,39719,39720,39801,39827,39846,39848,39851,40358,40364,40366,40367,40369,40372,40390,40391,40436,40927,41096,41106,41108,41110,41111,41116,41117,41118,41222,41268,41699,41703,41710,41722,42392,42398,42399,42401,42402,42404,42405,43096,44489,44503,46503,46523,46568) AND (
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1,3,4,42,92,99,120,161,164,167,201,213,227,231,268,283,297,316,321,341,345,370,494,572,746,1031,6252,7224,7583,7719,8723,9424,9960,11147,11251,11252,11253,12122,12187,12533,12636,12637,12692,12693,12694,12695,12868,12933,12934,12935,13416,13802,13803,13856,13987,13988,13989,14057,14134,14135,14136,14137,14223,14224,14307,14318,14319,14405,14493,14494,14495,14496,14497,14773,14778,14779,15150,15151,15152,15153,15167,15517,15636,15640,15641,15942,16030,16287,16310,17175,17201,17212,17269,18589,18590,18591,18592,19048,20165,20317,20320,20942)
  ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
              GROUP BY wp_posts.ID, wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id HAVING post_views > 0
              ORDER BY post_views DESC, wp_posts.ID DESC
              LIMIT 0, 5;
  # Time: 240106 19:36:19
  # User@Host: thesiteco3v94[thesiteco3v94] @ localhost []
  # Thread_id: 805  Schema: thesite_com_EnfJ52WV  QC_hit: No
  # Query_time: 11.439592  Lock_time: 0.000092  Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 13885
  # Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 198962
  # Tmp_tables: 1  Tmp_disk_tables: 1  Tmp_table_sizes: 34226176
  # Full_scan: No  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: Yes  Tmp_table_on_disk: Yes
  # Filesort: Yes  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0  Priority_queue: No
  SET timestamp=1704569779;
  SELECT   DISTINCT  wp_posts.*, SUM( COALESCE( pvc.count, 0 ) ) AS post_views
              FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) LEFT JOIN wp_post_views pvc ON pvc.id = wp_posts.ID AND pvc.type = 4
              WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (1402,1691,4351,28684,28692,30874,36540,36579,36581,36583,36589,37011,37014,37015,37017,38591,38599,38601,38604,38646,38648,38649,38651,38652,38655,38657,38800,38944,38945,38946,38947,39181,39642,39650,39661,39664,39678,39713,39714,39715,39716,39717,39718,39719,39720,39801,39827,39846,39848,39851,40358,40364,40366,40367,40369,40372,40390,40391,40436,40927,41096,41106,41108,41110,41111,41116,41117,41118,41222,41268,41699,41703,41710,41722,42392,42398,42399,42401,42402,42404,42405,43096,44489,44503,46503,46523,46568) AND (
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1,3,4,42,92,99,120,161,164,167,201,213,227,231,268,283,297,316,321,341,345,370,494,572,746,1031,6252,7224,7583,7719,8723,9424,9960,11147,11251,11252,11253,12122,12187,12533,12636,12637,12692,12693,12694,12695,12868,12933,12934,12935,13416,13802,13803,13856,13987,13988,13989,14057,14134,14135,14136,14137,14223,14224,14307,14318,14319,14405,14493,14494,14495,14496,14497,14773,14778,14779,15150,15151,15152,15153,15167,15517,15636,15640,15641,15942,16030,16287,16310,17175,17201,17212,17269,18589,18590,18591,18592,19048,20165,20317,20320,20942)
  ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
              GROUP BY wp_posts.ID, wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id HAVING post_views > 0
              ORDER BY post_views DESC, wp_posts.ID DESC
              LIMIT 0, 5;
  ```